# Android Q RingtonePicker now crashes app?

Tags: android, android-10.0

So I've been testing Android Q to make sure my apps won't have any issues and I notice the Ringtone picker now crashes the app if you try and launch it.

The error message is as below.

android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.RINGTONE_PICKER (has extras) }

I looked up the ringtonepreferences found here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/RingtonePreference

Now it says - This class was deprecated in API level Q.
Use the AndroidX Preference Library for consistent behavior across all devices. For more information on using the AndroidX Preference Library see Settings.

Is this just an issue because android Q is in beta or is this something I am going to need to change. I have two apps which I use the ringtonePicker for picking custom alarm sounds or notification sounds. Does anyone know any work around or should I just be patient and wait for Q to be further developed?

Edit: Here is a snippet of my code, maybe it is just an emulator issue..

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select Alarm Sound");
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, chosenAlarm1);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, false);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 5);
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing your code that is triggering this crash. Google is no longer supporting `RingtonePreference` and [will not provide an AndroidX edition](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37057453). Their recommendation (outlined in that issue) is for you to use `new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER)`. Is that what you are using?

Comment: FWIW, I just put together a scrap app that uses `RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER`, and I did not get any crashes. This was tested on a Google Pixel running Q Beta 2a (or whatever they're calling that patched Beta 2 release). If you are testing on an emulator, this might be an emulator issue.

Comment: Thanks for testing this :) it must be an emulator issue. Just was a little alarmed to have it crash like that because I have two apps which use this function. (Also added my code snippet)

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code snippet in a scrap project on a Pixel running Q Beta 2a, other than converting to Kotlin and dropping the extra that depended on your `Uri`. A psychedelic ringtone picker appeared:

[image: Q Ringtone Picker]

My changes should not affect `Intent` routing, so I think your problem is an emulator issue.